# An question about Cauchy Problem in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cauchy-problem

Yesterday, in [Brazilian School on Differential Geometry](http://www.impa.br/opencms/en/eventos/store_2016/evento_1612), a friend asked me the question:

> Given an (non-trivial) *initial data set* $(M,g,k)$ for the *Cauchy problem* in General Relativity. Is there some instant of time in your development, namely $t \neq 0$, such that the slice $(M_t,g_t, k_t)$ is isomorphic to $(M,g,k)$, in the sense of that are isometric Riemannian manifolds and has the same second fundamental form?

Unfortunately, I do not know any answer for this question. I will be grateful with any answer or reference that can clarify this question.

Comment: Technically, the Minkowski space is a periodic solution for any period you want. In fact, any static solution (with or without matter field) also qualifies. Presumably you want a non-trivial solution to your problem, where it is periodic but not stationary. On top of that, you may want to specify what constraint you want for the matter model. Allowing arbitrary matter model allows you to cook up very arbitrary solutions. May be you want vacuum to start. In which case you should look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04592

Comment: If you do not require some version of "finite energy" hypothesis, or are willing to look at spatially compact solutions,one easy way to get periodic solutions is to consider "plane wave" space-times. (Take the model [pp-wave solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime) and set the free function $H$ to be periodic in $u$, then you get a time (and space) periodic solution that roughly represents monochromatic gravitational radiation, the analogous solution to the linear wave equation would be $\phi(t,\vec{x}) = \sin(t - x_1)$.)

Comment: @WillieWong  thank you for yours comments and references :-)

Comment: Regarding your edit: most of the time additional conditions make the problem more restrictive. It makes more sense to ask about under what conditions there does _not_ exist non-stationary periodic solutions; because even without any conditions there does exist non-stationary periodic solutions.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Let me try to formulate better the question.

Comment: This is not a good title for the question. Unfortunately, I do not have a better idea for it.

Anyway, I hope to have improved the formulation of question (this was your original version).